# Elementary real inequality : $(1+x)^k \leq 1+(2^k -1)x$

Tags: inequality

I'm interested in the following inequality : let $x\in [0,1]$ and $k\geq 1$, $$ (1+x)^k \leq 1+(2^k -1)x.$$
How to tackle this inequality ? Is it "obvious" ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to prove it by induction? Another simpler way to prove it is using the fact that $(1+x)^k \le 1+kx$ and $k+1 \le 2^k$ (which are proved by induction as well).

Comment: @Crostul no i didn't try. Thank you. Though, the original inequality was for $k\geq 1$ real.

Comment: @Crostul Bernoulli's inequality assures $(1+x)^k\ge 1+kx$ for real $k\ge 1$. Besides induction won't work on its own for reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\in [0, 1]$,
\begin{align*}
(1 + x)^k 
  &= \sum_{n=0}^k \binom{k}{n} x^n
   = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^k \binom{k}{n} x^n
   \leq 1 + x\sum_{n=1}^k \binom{k}{n}
   = 1 + (2^k - 1)x.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Induction does the trick. For $k = 0$ both sides equal $1$. No suppose, the equation holds for $k$, we then have 
\begin{align*} (1+x)^{k+1} &= (1+x)(1+x)^k \\ &\le (1+x)\bigl(1+(2^k-1)x\bigr)\\ 
     &\le 1 + 2^kx  + (2^k -1)x^2\\
     &\le 1 + 2^kx + (2^k - 1)x\\
     &= 1 + (2^{k+1} - 1)x
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was kind of obvious afterall. I also add that the original inequality was for $k\geq 1$ real.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $k\ge1, x\ge0$, the function $f(x)=(1+x)^k$ is convex. In particular, successive secants have increasing slope, or the secant between endpoints of $[0, x]$ has lower slope than that between those of $[0,1]$.

Comment: P.S. Above method proves for all real $k\ge 1$...